# One-to-one self-relationship and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I would like to have entity which can have a child (one or zero). This child is same type as parent. I am not sure how to set entity framework becouse I would like to have two navigation properties for every entity. One for navigation to child and one for navigation to parent. Basically it is exactly the same structure as doubly linked list.

I think this table structure should be enough:

```
 int | id       | PK
 int | id_next  | FK
text | data
```

But how can I create navigation properties for next/prev items? I am able to create only navigation property for next item.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The problem here is that a one-to-one relation has a very specific requirement - FK value must be unique in the whole table. Once the uniqueness is not enforced you can add a second entity pointing to the same parent and you have a one-to-many relation.

To enforce this in a self referencing relation like you described in your example you will place an unique index on the `id_next` and it will work in SQL server. The problem is that entity framework doesn't support unique keys. Because of that entity framework is only able to build one-to-one relations between two different entity types where FK in the dependent the entity type is also its PK (the only way how to force FK to be unique) = both entities has same PK value. This cannot work with a self referencing relation because you cannot have two same PK values in one table.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in EF4 by specifying a 0..1 -> 0..1 relationship on the entity. Name one of the navigation properties "Previous" and the other "Next". This will create a hidden field on the underlying DB.

I haven't thoroughly tested this approach but it seemed to work when I created the database script.

Answer (score 0):

Research Tree structures in the Entity Framework.  You basically want a vertical tree (i.e. one branch).  The framework won't enforce only one branch, but you can manage that in your business logic.